# Calculate maximum number of repetitions of a matrix for a given memory limit

Tags: arrays, matlab, memory

While using `repmat`, I get this error:

```
Error using repmat
Requested 2192800x2400 (39.2GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays greater than this limit may take a
long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array size limit or preference panel for more information.
```

I would like a function that accepts two inputs: `input_array` and `max_mem`, where the first is the array I would like to replicate, and `max_mem` is a amount of memory in GBs. The function should return `N_max`, an integer that maximises the number of rows of `repmat(input_array, N_max, 1)` while constraining it to be within the memory limit specified by `max_mem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly

```
function N_max = foo (input_array, max_mem)

arrayInfo = whos('input_array');
arraySize = arrayInfo.bytes;

% max_mem in bytes, conversion if necessary
N_max     = floor(max_mem / arraySize);
```